# Postgres full text search: How to find document with at two or more key words?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Table A has column Summary, which is indexed using GIN on index column tsv.

select * from A where to_tsquery('vision & computer') @@ tsv works as, returns all data with vision/VISION and computer/COMPUTER etc...

The challenge is how to find the data which have at two words or more from a list of key words. For example, the list is:

1. Computer
2. vision
3. ReLu
4. Convolution
5. Google
6. classifer
   No result should be returned if the document has only one of the key words.
   Is there a way to do it without listing out all the combinations?

Tried to google but can't find anything so it kind of tells that I am really bad with searching by keywords.

Answer (score 0):

FTS search index provides no special provision for this.

Your options would either be to expand the query to "6 Choose 2" = 15 piped together pairs `'computer & vision | computer & relu | ... convolution & google | ...'`, or search for documents with any of the terms, and then filter those candidates to remove the ones that don't have at least two of the terms.

You might also be able to use ts_rank, but I don't know how reliably you could figure out what threshold to apply to the score.

Comment: thanks for the reply, hoping there may have some other ways. The complete list is about 100 words long...

Comment: may not be an answer but I ended use python to generate the combination. In case if anyone has similar challenge. just use this: itertools.combinations(iterable, r)